# JQuery ajax issue - PHP script not getting passed values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call given below:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('aid', qid);
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: M.cfg.wwwroot + '/mod/quiz/accessrule/mictest/miccheck.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I am passing a value (int) to the miccheck.php script where I want to set a session variable using that value. Here is my PHP script (miccheck.php)

```
$aid = $_POST['aid'];
$SESSION->miccheckpassed[$aid] = 1;
```

But somehow, the session variable is not set. Any help, please.

Comment: The session is stored in `$_SESSION` and you need to start it first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually did not mention details. I am using the code in a Moodle plugin. And Moodle starts the session internally when a user logs in. Further, Moodle provides the session as global variable ($SESSION) which can be access in any page when we call: global $SESSION;

Comment: Thanks everyone for your assistance. I noticed that $_SESSION['miccheckpassed'][$aid] was somehow causing the issue and not letting variable set in actual session object. So, I changed it to $miccheckpassed = 'miccheckpassed'.$aid; $_SESSION[$miccheckpassed] = 1; and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if you want this

```
$aid = $_POST['aid'];
$_SESSION['miccheckpassed'][$aid] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start session on the top of your php script and then assign the data to the variable in session. Something like below might help

```
<?php
session_start();
$aid = $_POST['aid'];
$_SESSION['miccheckpassed'][$aid] = 1;
?>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually did not mention details. I am using the code in a Moodle plugin. So, Moodle starts the session internally. Further, Moodle provides a session global variable which is available in any page when we call: